# Configure apache with fcgi

Tags: apache, apache2, xampp, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I'm trying to configure Apache 2.4 (XAMPP 1.8.3) with fcgi module. First, I copy the mod_fcgi.so file to apache/modules directory. After, I add the following line to httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
```

After that, I try to start Apache Server and don't start. It shows this message:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows 
Event Viewer for more clues.
If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums.
```

If I comment this line the server works.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got it working.

In php.ini, activate the right oci extension.
You have to use the oci extension that corresponds to your php version and your oracle.

You can uncomment the loadmodule for fcgi, but if you need it, in php.ini :

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

FcgidInitialEnv PATH "C:/xampp/php;C:/instantclient_12_1;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem;"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:/Windows"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:"
FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:/WINDOWS"
FcgidIOTimeout 64
FcgidConnectTimeout 16
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000 
FcgidMaxProcesses 50 
FcgidMaxRequestLen 8131072
# PHPRC is the location of the php.ini file
FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "C:/xampp/php"
FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000

<Files ~ "\.php$>"
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php
  FcgidWrapper "c:/xampp/php/php-cgi.exe" .php
</Files>
```

Patrick